# How to determine the direction of a vector (or its normal)

Tags: matlab, geometry

I like to determine the direction of the normals for each of the lines given in the code below. Is there a way i could do this in Matlab?

```
x = linspace(-10,10, 12);
y1 = -(0.5*x) + 1.333;
plot(x, y1); hold on

%2nd line
xd = 5;
plot(xd, x, 'o')

%vectors and normal vectors 
n1 = [0.5, 1]; v1 = [1, -0.5];
n2 = [-5, 0]; v2 = [0, 5];
angle = (acos(dot(v1, v2) / (norm(v1) * norm(v2))) * 180/pi)
```

Thank you.

Comment: What you mean by `direction`? You already have direction vectors.

Answer (score 0):

To determine the slope of a straight line, you can pick any two distinct points (p0, f(p0)) and (p1, f(p1)) on the line and determine the line's slope by (f(p1)-f(p0)) / (p1 - p0). Let's pick the first and last points on your lines (indexed by 1 and end).

The slope of the first line is:

```
slope = (y1(end) - y1(1)) / (x(end) - x(1));
```

which calculates to -0.5 - exactly what we would expect given your definition of that line.

The slope of the second line is:

```
slope = (x(end) - x(1)) / (xd - xd);
```

which is infinite since it is a vertical line.

The slope of a normal to a line is -1 divided by the slope of that line:

```
normal_slope = -1/slope;
```

MATLAB takes care of setting -1/inf == -1/(-inf) == 0 so you don't have to separate out the special case when the slope is infinite.

This calculation gives that the slope of the normal to line 1 is 2, and the slope of the normal to line 2 is 0, as expected.